# Font family was not working in React Native v"0.67.4"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, font-family

When I Install the app , I didn't show Font

Please anyone helpme

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

firstly import AppLoading

```
import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';
```

and than import your fonts which you installed it

```
import {
  JosefinSans_400Regular,
  JosefinSans_500Medium,
} from '@expo-google-fonts/josefin-sans'
```

create a fontsloaded var like this

```
let [fontsloaded] = useFonts({
    JosefinSans_500Medium,
  })
```

and than add a if condition for if your fonts is not loaded than the your app is loading

```
if (!fontsloaded){
   return <AppLoading/>
 }
```

all these things add on before your return statement

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).